# Confused about vertex definition in "Introduction to Linear Optimization"

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

This book gives definition 2.7 wrt a vertex.  It says:

Let $P$ be a polyhedron.  A vector $x \in P$ is a vertex of P if there exists some $c$ such taht $c^Tx < c^Ty$ for all $y$ satisfying $y \in P$ and $y \ne x$.

This implies that a vertex could be a point between to extreme points.  However, the text shows a figure, Figure 2.5, which states that $w$ is not a vertex.  There seems to be a conflict here.

To make things more concrete, here is an example:

Suppose $P$  is defined as $x_1 + x_2 = 1$ subject to $x > 0$.  I can make $c = [1, 1]$ and then make $x=[0.5, 0.5]$  which is not an extreme point, but still satisfies definition 2.7.  What am I missing here?

Comment: what definition of extreme point are you using?

Comment: Your point $x$ does not satisfy the definition of vertex. $c^Ty=c^Tx$. for $y=(1,0)$.

Comment: The definition says the vector is, say, the top point on a pyramid. The meaning of $c^T$  is just a rotation of viewpoint....think in terms of "no other polyhedron point is this high"

Comment: @GReyes Actually, Im confused.  (1,0) and (0,1) are clearly vertices are they not?

Comment: @GReyes  I understand the geometric interpretation, but i am having trouble understanding exactly what the math is saying.

Comment: I get it.  There just has to be some c for which the inequality holds, not all c.

Comment: Yes, they are vertices, but you need to choose a different linear form to reveal this fact (a form whose level lines only touch the polygon at the vertex)

Answer (score 1):

The definition has a strict inequality. Your counterexample has a weak one.

Comment: So then (1,0) and (0,1) are not vertices.  Is this correct?

Comment: No. $v = (1,0)$ is a vertex: Let $c = (-1, 0)$. Then $c^Tv = -1$, which is less than $c^Tp$ for all the other points  $p \in P$. The geometry captured by this definition is that there is a hyperplane (the one normal to the $c$ you found) that meets the set at just one point. All the other points are on the same side of that hyperplane.